# Implementing Single Sign-On (SSO) across Multiple Domains with AWS Cognito in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, nodes

I am currently working on a project where I have multiple domains, and I am using AWS Cognito for Single Sign-On (SSO). My tech stack involves Node.js for server-side development and AWS Cognito for handling authentication through its APIs.

The specific challenge I am facing is achieving automatic login across different websites (website1, website2, website3) after the user has logged in on the first website (website1). I have researched and implemented AWS Cognito for SSO, but I'm still unable to make the seamless transition between domains upon user login.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am unable to get the website1 accessToken in website2 and website3. 
So i want the solution from where i can get the token from these three websites.